# Cross-platform daemon/service stop and start

Tags: services, cross-platform, daemon

Is there a tool which can control daemons/services in a cross-platform manner?

In programming there are different build tools that allow you to build software from source on different platforms; the tool will take care of detecting the capabilities of the particular machine and locate libraries, compilers, etc. CMake is an example.

There's a similar problem with controlling daemon's. Depending on the OS, if I want to  start a daemon I might use

```
stop-start-daemon -S mydaemon
```

or perhaps call a script like

```
/etc/init.d/mydaemon start
```

or if `systemctl` is the tool of choice then

```
systemctl start mydaemon
```

And if I'm on Windows then I could use either `net start myservice` or `sc start myservice`.

Is there a tool, script, or other canonical method for handling this scenario? I don't need fine-grained control; just stop and start, but I'd like to be able to deploy my own software on multiple systems using the same script.

Comment: do you have the differences, maybe I can write something

Answer (score 3):

To directly answer your question: no, there is not a cross platform way to start/stop/control daemons.

To indirectly answer your question: the typical way this is handled is by baking that kind of functionality into your program and installers (makefiles/build files/msi packages/zips whatever).

If I have a daemonized program that I am building (a program that is intended to run in the background or as a service), I build out the 'start/stop' scripts by hand (with some helpful copy/paste) and then zip up either the source or precompiled binary with the platform of choices control script that is then called the same way across each platform (i.e. `myservice -start` or `myservice -stop`, etc. etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Needing this myself for my own software products, I decided to write it:

https://github.com/cubiclesoft/service-manager/

It isn't quite a flawless solution due to each platform needing its own precompiled binary.  However, the interface is a lot more consistent than what we have at the moment.  Service Manager is probably best used as a cross-platform service *deployment* tool, which meets your latter need for deploying your own software, rather than a general start/stop tool.  That is, you write some code that you want to turn into a system service and make it easy and reliable to deploy on other machines regardless of OS.

However, it can also be used to start/stop other Service Manager enabled services.  So as long as all the services you want to control are running under Service Manager, you can use a single tool to start and stop those services.